The cross-sectional regression formulae in Asset Pricing by Cochrane (2005) do not make sense to me
I am reading Asset Pricing by Cochrane (2005) and I understand the theory behind the formulae but I question the validity. Clearly, I'm overlooking something.
On page 237 of the book, the author states: In an OLS regression $Y = X\beta +u$ and $E(uu') = \Omega$ the variance of $\beta$ estimate is
$$
Var(\hat{\beta}) = (X'X)^{-1} X' \Omega X(X'X)^{-1}
$$
and the residual covariance matrix is
$$
Var(y-\hat{y}) = [I - X(X'X)^{-1}X']\Omega[I - X(X'X)^{-1}X']'
$$
I disagree.
If $Var(u) = \Omega$ where $\Omega \ne \sigma^2 I$ then the solution to the regression equation is no longer $\hat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$. Now, the solution is $\hat{\beta} = (X'\Omega^{-1}X)^{-1}X'\Omega^{-1}y$ and this gives
$$
Var(\hat{\beta}) = (X'\Omega^{-1}X)^{-1}
$$
and
$$
Var(y-\hat{y}) = \Omega - X(X'\Omega^{-1}X)^{-1}X'
$$
What am I missing? The OLS regression assumes $\Omega = \sigma^2I$ which is why we get $Var(\hat{\beta}) = (X'X)^{-1} X' \Omega X(X'X)^{-1} = \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}$. However, if $\Omega \ne \sigma^2I$ then the whole formula needs recomputing because the solution is no longer the same form.

There is nothing wrong with considering properties of estimators under different sets of assumptions. Cochrane considers properties of OLS under assumptions that do not make OLS BLUE. Fine. Econometrics textbooks do that, and Cochrane's textbook has a lot of econometrics in it. It is good to know what happens with the OLS estimator when the error variance matrix is not $\sigma^2 I$.
Also, the GLS solution you are suggesting is infeasible unless we know the true error variance matrix (which we typically do not). And when we replace GLS with feasible GLS (FGLS), we may do better or worse than with OLS in small or medium samples. So OLS can be useful in a finite sample even if FGLS would be superior asymptotically.
